# Cancel hoverIntent timer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've used jQuery and hoverIntent plugin many times, for dropdown menus and advanced navigation that should be a bit more elegant. But I've run into a problem.

I have a menu with a clickable li element that also has a hover. **If someone clicks it before the intent timer triggers I want to cancel the hoverintent**, just because it looks nicer.

I can't figure out how though, designer first, coder second. This is what calls the intent:

```
$('#navigationContainer ul li').hoverIntent(configDown);
```

It's got a variable configDown that defines sensitivity etc. And two functions called slideUp and slideDown. Everything works perfectly.

If someone clicks this same element, I want to cancel the hoverIntent. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than cancel the hoverIntent, modify the code within the hoverIntent callbacks to first check if the `li` is clicked:

```
var configDown = {
    slideUp: function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('no-intent')) return;
        // slide up
    },
    slideDown: function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('no-intent')) return;
        // slide down
    }
};

$('#navigationContainer ul li').click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('no-intent');
}).hoverIntent(configDown);
```

Unless you have a good delay on the hoverIntent though, it may be tricky to trigger this correctly (you might end up clicking just after the hoverIntent is triggered), but the basic idea is there for you to tweak.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to work well. One has to click really fast, but I'm only adding it to avoid the visual effect before the new page loads for "quick" users.